# How to filter API JSON response where there is an error to remove issue records

Tags: python, json, api, filter

I am attempting to call an API which returns a list of reports that were previously generated, with a timestamp and download URL. I then am looking to sort the data based on latest generated report and return the download URL. However, some of the reports were run in error, so there is no download URL and this key is replaced with 'error'. Is there a way to filter these records out of the JSON response so that I can get the latest download URL?

```
json_obj = {'entries': [{'download_url': 'https://www.google.com', 'id': '4d82cc91-be1e-4d79-a9c9-b9695fc9bfc0', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-03T15:15:30.059Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-03T15:15:30.140Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'}, {'download_url': 'https://www.cnn.com', 'id': 'f2c620fb-1064-4baf-98f9-e805f48164b0', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-03T15:07:10.358Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-03T15:07:10.441Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'}, {'download_url': 'https://www.nbc.com', 'id': '9ed29931-3d34-4db9-8e0a-812687785d9e', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-03T15:03:20.597Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-03T15:03:20.664Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'},{'error': {'message': 'http error 500: Internal Server Error'}, 'id': 'b49dcf8d-e61f-4366-925d-71d18f249b5e', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-02T12:34:03.930Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-02T17:55:11.468Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'}, {'error': {'message': 'http error 500: Internal Server Error'}, 'id': 'cf92e76e-528e-4209-b7a9-899861184c64', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-02T12:24:01.591Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-02T17:56:28.577Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'}, {'download_url': 'https://www.espn.com', 'id': 'a6f0a733-268c-4fa3-8212-414780b47317', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-01T12:24:22.540Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-01T12:24:22.643Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'}]}

sorted_obj = dict(json_obj)
sorted_obj['entries'] = sorted(json_obj['entries'], key=lambda x : x['completed_at'], reverse=False)

print(sorted_obj)

for entry in sorted_obj['entries']: url2 = entry['download_url']

response3 = requests.request("GET", url2, headers=headers, verify = False)
```

The idea would be to filter out the JSON records that have an "error" so the only remaining records have a download URL.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I edited the original post with a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use a [try/except block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to ignore entries without a `download_url`

```
json_obj = {'entries': [{'download_url': 'https://www.google.com', 'id': '4d82cc91-be1e-4d79-a9c9-b9695fc9bfc0', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-03T15:15:30.059Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-03T15:15:30.140Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'}, {'download_url': 'https://www.cnn.com', 'id': 'f2c620fb-1064-4baf-98f9-e805f48164b0', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-03T15:07:10.358Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-03T15:07:10.441Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'}, {'download_url': 'https://www.nbc.com', 'id': '9ed29931-3d34-4db9-8e0a-812687785d9e', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-03T15:03:20.597Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-03T15:03:20.664Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'},{'error': {'message': 'http error 500: Internal Server Error'}, 'id': 'b49dcf8d-e61f-4366-925d-71d18f249b5e', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-02T12:34:03.930Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-02T17:55:11.468Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'}, {'error': {'message': 'http error 500: Internal Server Error'}, 'id': 'cf92e76e-528e-4209-b7a9-899861184c64', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-02T12:24:01.591Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-02T17:56:28.577Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'}, {'download_url': 'https://www.espn.com', 'id': 'a6f0a733-268c-4fa3-8212-414780b47317', 'format': 'csv', 'created_at': '2021-09-01T12:24:22.540Z', 'completed_at': '2021-09-01T12:24:22.643Z', 'params': {'format': 'csv', 'domain': 'X'}, 'title': 'Y', 'report_type': 'issues-csv'}]}

sorted_obj = dict(json_obj)
sorted_obj['entries'] = sorted(json_obj['entries'], key=lambda x : x['completed_at'], reverse=False)

download_urls = []
for entry in sorted_obj['entries']:
    try:
        download_urls.append(entry['download_url'])
    except KeyError:
        print(f"Skipping {entry}")
        pass

print(download_urls)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! That worked great to skip over those entries, but now in this line of code "for entry in download_urls['entries']: url2 = entry['download_url']",  when trying to identify url2 as the latest download_url I am getting a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str response. Would you happen to know a way around that?

Comment: No problem! `download_urls` is a list of strings already containing the download_url index, there's no need for this loop. Instead you can pass `download_urls` directly to requests like this `for url in download_urls: response3 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify = False)`